# Objective C: Request for member XXX in something not a structure or union. (Core Data)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am hitting this error when implementing core data.

I have created a entity 'FlashCard' with the attribute 'question' and 'answer'. Both the attributes are of NSString type.

After inserting a new object into the NSManaged Object, I tried to set the 2 attributes as seen below.

```
 NSManagedObject *newCard = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FlashCard" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 newCard.question = thisQuestion;
 newCard.answer = thisAnswer;
```

But when I try to compile the code, I am hitting the error "Request for member 'question' in something is not a structure or union'. I get the same error for newCard.answer line.

Any advise on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated!

Zhen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared newCard as an NSManagedObject, then tried to access properties that NSManagedObject doesn't define.

Core Data gives you the option of using a custom subclass of NSManagedObject to represent entities. If you're doing this then, as others have suggested, you need to declare newCard as an instance of that subclass (in case you're not doing this, you'll have to write the class and declare the properties yourself if you want to use the 'dot' property syntax --- core data doesn't automatically create a subclass of NSManagedObject for each entity type)

Also, you don't have to use your own subclass or write accessors just to access a managed object's attributes and relationships. If you don't need to add any custom logic to FlashCard yet, you can use key value coding on an NSManagedObject instead. This would work fine:

```
NSManagedObject *newCard = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FlashCard" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[newCard setValue: thisQuestion forKey: @"question"];
[newCard setValue: thisAnswer forKey: @"answer"];
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it's working fine now. Can I just clarify one point? In my Flash.h file, I have @dynamic question, answer. You are saying that there is not sufficient for me to access both attributes via dot notation? And I need to declare a FlashCard *newCard instance before I can use the dot notation?

Comment: @Zhen, make sure you've defined question and answer as properties in the `FlashCard` header -- see my comment below.

Comment: @Zhen: Like conmulligan says, you need to use @property.... to declare the properties in the header file. @dynamic should go in your implementation file. it doesn't actually do anything except tell the compiler not to complain that the property hasn't been implemented (core data will implement the property for you at runtime)

Answer (score 5):

Your `newCard` instance should be of type `FlashCard` not `NSManagedObject`; otherwise, the compiler won't know that `newCard` has the properties `question` and `answer`.

```
FlashCard *newCard = (FlashCard *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FlashCard" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
newCard.question = thisQuestion;
newCard.answer = thisAnswer;
```

Comment: What if they haven't created a sub-class for FlashCard?

Comment: I'm assuming a FlashCard class exists because he's trying to access properties using the dot notation.

Comment: yes I have a FlashCard class, however, I still hit the error when trying to cast it with (FlashCard *) as you suggest. Can I check if there is anything else I am missing? I have a Flash.h file which contains @dynamic question, answer (attributes)

Comment: @Zhen, are they defined as properties? You should have `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *question;@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *answer;` in your `FlashCard.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "FlashCard.h"
```

Is "FlashCard.h" included at the top of this file?

Comment: yes I have included it in the top of the file. However I was still hitting this issue even with that.